# I got Some wrong answers in my test cases,

Tags: c

My assignment is:
"Input : m,n
that the program get n characters just including 'W' and 'B' in m lines.
Output: if quantity of 'W's are even in each column it'll return a 'B' instead else it returns 'F'.

> Note : We Are NOT allowed to use arrays!

Example:
input:

```
3 2
WBW
BBW
```

Output:

```
FBB
```

My Code :

```
scanf("%d %d",&n,&m);
for(int i=1;i<=m;i++)
{
    str = 0;
    for(int j=1;j<=n+1;j++)
    {
       scanf("%c",&c);

       if(c=='W')
           str = str*1000+1;
       else
            str = str*1000;
    }//end of getting characters

    sumstr += str;
}//end of getting lines

//Reversing the "sumstr"
while(sumstr>0)
{
    a = sumstr%1000;
    reverse = (reverse+a)*1000;
    sumstr/=1000;
}
reverse/=1000;

for(int k =1;k<=n;k++)
{
    a=reverse%1000;

    if(a%2==0)
        printf("B");
    else
        printf("F");
   reverse /= 1000;
}//End of printing 'B' and 'F'
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please tell us what input you give, what output was expected, and what output you actually get.

Comment: Your first line `scanf("%d %d",&n,&m);` will not consume the space following the second number (`m`). You can maybe fix your code by checking for `c==' ' || c=='\n'` inside the `for()` loop. Or better still, ignore everything I just said and learn how to use a debugger. Seriously, it's worth the effort, and this is a great opportunity to get started.

Comment: @Ali Hatami The description does not correspond to examples. For example n is not a number of characters in a row.

Comment: Would the text: _Input : m,n that the program get n characters just including 'W' and 'B' in m lines_. be better stated as: _Input : rows,cols. Where the program will then expect the user to input rows*cols characters comprised only of 'W' or 'B'. The program will arrange this input into m columns of n rows_?  Using variable names that are descriptive of what they are used for is preferable ***always***.

Comment: How big can `n` or `m` be? Are you aware of the  maximum value an `int` can store and what happens in case of overflow? Is there a particular reason why you are not storing the inputs or some partial result in an array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several items in your code that are problematic, including such things as your prompt for user input:  `scanf("%d %d",&n,&m);`.  This will not handle the white space that comes with the user input.

These are not hard rules, just some suggestions:
(followed by example code with alternative methods of user input and temporary data storage.)

- When asking for user input, use simple clear directions that allow no ambiguity.
- Allow for 1 entry at a time.
- Use variable values that describe what you are doing. (`rows` `cols` are more descriptive than
  `m` `n`)
- Create an appropriate container for holding user data as it is entered.

For example:

```
int main(void)
{
    char str[4];
    int chr;
    int rows, cols;
    int i, j;

    char sDataConv[][2] = { "W", "B" };

    printf("Enter number of rows: ");
    if(fgets(str, 4, stdin)) 
    {
        rows = atoi(str);   
    }
    printf("Enter number of columns: ");
    if(fgets(str, 4, stdin)) 
    {
        cols = atoi(str);   
    }
    int array[rows][cols];//read data in as char values such as 'W' and 'B'
    memset(array, 0, sizeof(array));

    //Now a loop can be used prompting user
    //to enter  values, and placing values
    //into array as they are entered, eg using
    // array[i][j] = getc(stdin);
    // if((array[i][j] == 'W') || (array[i][j] == 'B'))

    for(i = 0; i<rows; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0;j<cols;j++)
        {
            printf("Enter either W or B one at a time");
            if(fgets(str, 4, stdin))
            {
                array[i][j] = str[0];
                //test - limit to allow only W or B
                while(!((array[i][j] == 'W') || (array[i][j] == 'B')))
                {
                    printf("Wrong entry, enter either W or B.");
                    if(fgets(str, 4, stdin))
                    {
                        array[i][j] = str[0];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    //display data entered
    for(i = 0; i<rows; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0;j<cols;j++)
        {
            printf("%c ", array[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }



    return 0;
}
```

This should provide a start. The rest is up to you, but the array should help to make the comparisons, and present results.

Comment: Fair enough, yet if `array` could be a pointer, I'd go for `sizeof array[0][0] * rows * cols` to 1) not have to maintain/check the type and 2) avoid overflow in extreme cases of `int*int*size_t`